# Not returning FCM token on Digital Signage Device

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I'm working on react native project that receiving notifications using firebase cloud messaging service. After I implement the code for the mobile apps I'm getting FCM token properly. when I install on it digital signage devices screen device I'm getting FMC permission. but failed in getToken methods. I have a doubt that signage device not containing google play services. have any suggestions?

```
export const printFcm = () => dispatch => {
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging
.hasPermission()
.then(enabled => {
if (enabled) {
messaging
.getToken()
.then(fcm_token => {
dispatch({
type: FCM_TOKEN,
payload: fcm_token
});
})
.catch(getFcmErr => {
alert(JSON.stringify(getFcmErr));
});
} else {
alert("Get Permissions NO");
}
})
.catch(e => {
alert("Get Permissions failed");
});
};
```

here I'm getting alert with "Get Permissions failed" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cause was device not support for google play services